# Given a population mean and standard deviation of 14.2% and 2.3%, respectively, what is the probability that a sample value will be below 12%?

Tags: probability, statistics

This question is meant to make use of the unit normal table, and the solution I have says to use the R(x) function, but shouldn't you use F(x) if you are looking for the probability of it falling below x?

Comment: Without writing down your assumptions about the distribution of the population as well as how your sample is drawn the answer to the question is "we don't know".

Comment: You should write the mean and standard deviation as decimals, as percentages are likely to be confused with percentiles of the distribution.

Comment: Also, what do r(x) and f(x) mean in this problem?

Comment: Apologies for missing details.  It is a normal distribution.  Please refer to [this link](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/using-fe-reference-tables-standard-normal-distribution-see-page-42-fe-reverence-book-proba-q24761350) for F(x) and R(x).  From my review book, F(x) is the area from negative infinity to x, and R(x) is the area from x to infinity.

Comment: In R, code `pnorm(12, 14.3, 2.3)` returns $ 0.1586553.$ Or standardize, use printed normal tables, and get a similar, slightly less accurate, answer. Or use the Empirical Rule which states that the probability in a (roughly) normal distribution between $\mu \pm \sigma$ is 68%, leaving 32% in both of the two tails above and below $\mu\pm\sigma$ to have 16% each.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a normal distribution, first calculate the $z$-score of $0.12$, which is just:

$$z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma} = \frac{0.12 - 0.142}{0.023} \approx -0.957$$

Then you can use the unit normal table to find the probability.

---

Regarding your comment: Yes, it is easier to use $F(x)$ instead of $R(x)$. However, since the total area under the normal distribution is $1$, $F(x) =  1 - R(x)$, so it does not matter which function you use after all.